# Jasper Table does not display colum border when data overflow occurs to next iReport page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem for jasper table.

1. When some of my column in the table have too long data overflow to the next page, the other column isn't display its column border as the attached file.
2. In case the first row of the table have too long data, it will be shifed to display on the next page. What I want is to shift this row next to the column header and split overflow content to the next page. Is this possible?

I noticed that this problem appears only when I add a table group.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5266eaf6-845e-4983-9b4a-79f06c5bbac4">
 <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
 <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
 <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
 <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="95f1333e-f6b7-49e1-bc0f-e6aa57c31c09">
  <queryString>
   <![CDATA[select 'surname' f1,'name' f2, 'patronymic' f3,'workplace' f4, 'groupname' f5 from dual
union all
select 'surname123' f1,'name123' f2, 'patronymic123' f3,'workplaceworkplaceworkplaceworworkplakplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDASDASDASDASDASSSSSSworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDASDASDASDASDASSSSSSworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDASDASDASDASDASSSSSSworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDASDASDASDASDASSSSSSworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDASDASDASDASDASSSSSSkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceworkplaceASDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDASDASDASDASDASSSSSS' f4, 'groupname' f5 from dual
union all
select 'surnameN' f1,'nameN' f2, 'patronymicN' f3,'workplaceN' f4, 'groupname' f5 from dual]]>
  </queryString>
  <field name="F1" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="F2" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="F3" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="F4" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="F5" class="java.lang.String"/>
 </subDataset>
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[select * from dual]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="DUMMY" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <detail>
  <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
   <componentElement>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="125" uuid="8942c29d-58eb-4bf4-8ac2-05a30aa3ba5c"/>
    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
     <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="78e2207b-92f9-4050-9390-474b5af01493">
      <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
     </datasetRun>
     <jr:columnGroup width="360" uuid="b7b3cd06-dec8-4e81-80a0-b6cf4231fb7c">
      <jr:tableHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
       <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="360" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="f26d8bb9-b1ed-49c0-9e78-c8a452c01bba"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{F5}]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>
      </jr:tableHeader>
      <jr:column width="90" uuid="14650440-d1d9-466c-973c-17d2e4f6408f">
       <jr:detailCell height="52" rowSpan="1">
        <box>
         <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
        </box>
        <textField>
         <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="52" uuid="6a1b3f83-a53d-4a56-99e9-fec5f47b9470"/>
         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{F1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
       </jr:detailCell>
      </jr:column>
      <jr:column width="90" uuid="8bc26be4-d780-4bc3-9456-177f546c9323">
       <jr:detailCell height="52" rowSpan="1">
        <box>
         <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
        </box>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
         <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="52" uuid="6eb7e7e1-89c4-48f2-92df-657a9698b8c1"/>
         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{F2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
       </jr:detailCell>
      </jr:column>
      <jr:column width="90" uuid="fffd456c-9c45-4f35-91bb-dc84abebdb65">
       <jr:detailCell height="52" rowSpan="1">
        <box>
         <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
        </box>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
         <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="52" uuid="c7e3823b-6e24-4e27-9659-f87655cdc978"/>
         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{F3}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
       </jr:detailCell>
      </jr:column>
      <jr:column width="90" uuid="2caf64d9-c897-41e0-9547-82aafbcc5f1a">
       <jr:detailCell height="52" rowSpan="1">
        <box>
         <pen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <topPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <leftPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <bottomPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
         <rightPen lineWidth="1.25"/>
        </box>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
         <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="52" uuid="fe6461b2-b8b5-4694-81fb-c6fec9f3f0ac"/>
         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{F4}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
       </jr:detailCell>
      </jr:column>
     </jr:columnGroup>
    </jr:table>
   </componentElement>
  </band>
 </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise it is impossible to help you.